# Coefficient Calculation on Fourier Series Under two minutes, Yes, How?!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, fourier-series

Example of one Question for preparing the entrance exam: Fourier series of function:

$$ f(x)=f(x+2\pi), f(x) =\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    1 &     & -\pi <x<0 \\
    \sin x &  & 0<x<\pi \\
  \end{array}
\right. $$

be like as:

$$ f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos nx+b_n \sin nx)   $$

(Question) so the coefficient is:

$$a_n=0,n=2k+1,b_n=0,n=2k$$

My challenge is via the coefficient,  (i.e: calculate the coefficient) under two minutes that consider for each question? Is there any way to calculate this shortly?

Option $1) a_n=0,n=2k+1,b_n=0,n=2k+1$

Option $2) a_n=0,n=2k,b_n=0,n=2k+1$

Option $3) a_n=0,n=2k,b_n=0,n=2k$

Option $4) a_n=0,n=2k+1,b_n=0,n=2k $ (solution)

Very nice short solution is get by my friends, it's not understandable for me, anyone could describe it?

[image]

Comment: $\pi a_n = \int_{-\pi}^0 \cos(nx) dx+\int_{0}^\pi \sin(x)\cos(nx) dx$ and $\pi b_n = \int_{-\pi}^0 \sin(nx) dx+\int_{0}^\pi \sin(x)\sin(nx) dx$ nothing hard here, if you want you can write $\sin,\cos$ in term of $e^{i  x}$

Comment: you don't know how to compute $\displaystyle\int_A^B \frac{e^{i  x}-e^{i x}}{2i}\frac{e^{i n x}+e^{-i n x}}{2} dx$ ?

Comment: You must give options for doing it in under 2 minutes

Comment: come on.. $\int_A^B e^{i c x} dx = \frac{e^{i c B}-e^{ic A}}{i c}$ .. you are supposed to know complex numbers and $e^z$ before looking at the Fourier series

Comment: no. explain your method if you have one

Comment: well this is ok, where is the problem ? and $2\sin(a)\cos(b) = \sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)$ can be derived from $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ so it is really the same method

Comment: if you don't explain what you don't understand then nobody can help you

Comment: @user1952009 the second answer be wrong, am I right? $b_n$ calculation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not hard:

I think:

$$a_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi} (\int\limits_{-\pi}^{0}-1cos(nx)dx + \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)cos(nx) dx) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)cos(nx) dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{cos(n\pi)+1}{1-n^2}$$

$$b_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi} (\int\limits_{-\pi}^{0}-1sin(nx)dx + \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)sin(nx) dx)=\frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{cos(nx)}{n}|_{-\pi}^{0} + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{\pi}{2}) $$

Answer (score 2):

They're not asking for all the coefficients, just which ones are zero.

Your friend seems to be making arguments to linearity. In the first two (top) graphs, they split into the "1" part and the "sin" part, each 0 on the half of the period. Then he writes the first part as a sum again: a constant 1/2, and an alternating-sign 1/2. (The first two graphs on the bottom row). Similarly with sin, he gets a $\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)$ and a $\frac{1}{2}|\sin(x)|$ term. The original function is the sum of these four terms, so the Fourier transform is the sum of the Fourier transforms of these four terms.

The Fourier transform of the first term is trivial: $a_0=1$. The Fourier transform of the third term is also trivial: $b_1 = 1$. This is actually already enough to fully determine the answer then! (Note: this is assuming that the second and fourth terms don't completely cancel those out. Comparing the magnitudes I can quickly convince myself of this.)

To be slightly more rigorous, your friend considers the parity of coefficients on the other terms as well. The second term has all the odd part left, and the fourth term has all the even part left, so the second gives us $b_n$ terms and the fourth gives $a_n$ terms. In the second term, it's completely odd around $x=\pi$, so all terms must be odd frequencies ($n=2k+1$). Similarly on the fourth one, the entire function is even around $x=\pi$, so everything must be even frequencies so as to maintain that symmetry ($n=2k$).

Comment: Wow very nice, Is it possible to make more clearer with any picture your second and third paragraph?

Comment: I'm not sure where I could add a graph that wouldn't be easier to refer to the picture you provided. But if you have additional questions/points of confusion I'm happy to explain (or provide a picture if need be). :)

Comment: okey thanks so much, 1) what do you mean by "your friend considers the parity of coefficients on the other terms as well" and 2) how you sure about " this is assuming that the second and fourth terms don't completely cancel those out" ?

Comment: So, we showed that the first term adds $a_0=1$. The second and third terms are odd so can't contribute any $a_n$. The fourth term is even so could add or subtract to $a_0$, so its true value is something different. But the important thing is: is $a_0$ exactly 0? The fourth term is positive on average, so its $a_0 > 0$, so for the original function, $a_0 > 1$, which is sufficient to rule out options (3) and (4). For the $b_1$ term similarly, we get $b_1 = 1$ contribution from the third term. The second term can add, but is also positive, so $b_1 > 1$ overall, eliminating option (1).

Comment: This is how I convinced myself of that. Your friend explicitly computed that $a_{2k+1} = 0$ and $b_{2k} = 0$ for all terms, which provides the desired guarantees.

Comment: would you please describe " Then he writes the first part as a sum again: a constant 1/2, and an alternating-sign 1/2." with example? i didnt get the point

Comment: Label the graphs (and their functions) G1, G2, H1, H2, H3, and H4. He wrote G1 = H1 + H2. Here G1 is 1 on $[-\pi,0]$ and 0 elsewhere (with period $2\pi$). H1 is 1/2 everywhere. H2 is 1/2 on $[-\pi,0]$ and 1/2 on $[0,\pi]$. You can verify that H1 and H2 add up to G1. H1 has just $a_0$ and H2 has just $a_{2k}$.

Comment: Thanks, one remaining problem is about integrals, I have one problem in calculating $b_n$, would you please consider it in your answer ? I check the other answer in bellow, I think it's wrong for $b_n$ ?